# Is it possible to get coordinates (x,y) without trial and error in pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

An example I would like to give is I wanted to figure out the coordinates of the **“Google Search”** button please see this image here.  [Button I want to get coordinates of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABFRo.png)

My question is,

Is there a way to figure out the (x,y) coordinates of this button in Pyautogui without trial and error is there a function in pyautogui that can be used as Im not really aware of any?

Comment: pyautogui has to scan the screen to find the button. You could use something like selenium instead if you want to interact with web pages automatically.

Comment: @Loocid Sure I will look into selenium but there isn't any function like this in pyautogui right?

Comment: No. They have built in functions to scan for an image, but that is still doing "trial and error" int the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a screenshot of the button and use the `locateCenterOnScreen` function from `pyautogui`. I believe that will be sufficient for your question. However, if you need something more, there are a few other `locate` functions, you can read their documentation [here](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html).

Note that you can specify a `confidence` parameter to the functions if they get it wrong (requires installing `openCV`).

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
import pyautogui, sys
print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')

try:

     while True:
 
          x, y = pyautogui.position()    
          positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)        
          print(positionStr, end='')        
          print('\b' * len(positionStr), end='', flush=True) 
except KeyboardInterrupt: print('\n')
```

More info in the docs: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html